# How to set up Gogle's People API

Tags: php, google-people-api

I've been trying to set up the sample [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php#step_2_set_up_the_sample).

When I try running it as is I get the following error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redirect URI in /opt/lampp/htdocs/rev_wip/vendor/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php:685
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/rev_wip/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php(406): Google\Auth\OAuth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/rev_wip/quickstart.php(40): Google\Client->createAuthUrl()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/rev_wip/quickstart.php(64): getClient()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/rev_wip/vendor/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php on line 685
```

So I add a URI :

```
// $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/rev_wip/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/rev_wip/' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
```

Now I get (when I run it on the browser) :

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Learn more
The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.

redirect_uri: http://localhost/rev_wip/quickstart.php
```

I am thinking that this example is a **Desktop APP** and so there should be no Redirect URI. I, however get the common redirect URI error when I run it on the CLI.

How should I go about it?

Thank you all in advance.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('People API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath   = __DIR__ . '/token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath) , true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        }
        else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode    = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath) , 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client    = getClient();
$service   = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

// Print the names for up to 10 connections.
$optParams = array(
    'pageSize'           => 10,
    'personFields'           => 'names,emailAddresses',
);
$results   = $service
->people_connections
->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);

if (count($results->getConnections()) == 0) {
    print "No connections found.\n";
}
else {
    print "People:\n";
    foreach ($results->getConnections() as $person) {
        if (count($person->getNames()) == 0) {
            print "No names found for this connection\n";
        }
        else {
            $names = $person->getNames();
            $name  = $names[0];
            printf("%s\n", $name->getDisplayName());
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried with a publicly accessible `$redirect_uri`?

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial you're linking to there's a section called "Troubleshooting" under which there's a section about the exact error you're facing:

https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php#uncaught_invalidargumentexception_missing_the_required_redirect_uri

> Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: missing the required redirect URI
>
> This error occurs when the credentials.json file used contains a client ID of the wrong type.
> This code requires an OAuth client ID of type Other, which will be
> created for you when using the button in Step 1. If creating your own
> client ID please ensure you select the correct type.

This suggests you didn't complete step 1 properly or that you have supplied your own client ID of the wrong type.

Comment: Thank you @marmor. Let me try it out. I'll let you know how it works and accept your answer.